# How to get values from #result-set-1 in SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring

When executing SimpleJdbcCall, I get two parameters #result-set-1, #update-count-1

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("name", "something");
Map<String, Object> resultFromProcedure = cstmt.execute(parameterSource);
```

## #result-set-1 have variables

```
[{
 id = 123,
 name = "something",
 accountnumber = 123456,
 balance = 789999
}]
```

Everything is fine until I tried to access

```
resultFromProcedure.get("accountnumber")
```

Which getting null. The Question is how to access the values in #result-set-1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly; `Map<String, Object> resultFromProcedure` consist of 2 entries having keys `#result-set-1` and `#update-count-1`.

And the object of `#result-set-1` is an object having 4 member variables. (If it is a String, then you'd need to convert the Json to a Java Object ([Example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)))

Thus your call to `resultFromProcedure.get("accountnumber")` is trying to fetch an object using the key `accountnumber`, but the map doesn't contain that key. You need to first get the object for `#result-set-1` e.g.

```
SomeDTO someDTO = resultFromProcedure.get("#result-set-1");
```

Then you can call

```
someDTO.getAccountNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

As there could be more than one result set, SimpleJdbcCall returns an object in the arraylist within another map marked as "#result-set-1". To access the values in it, try the following:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList = (ArrayList) resultFromProcedure.get("#result-set-1");
Map resultMap = (Map) arrayList.get(0);

System.out.println("Account Number: " + resultMap.get("accountnumber"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a Rowmapper for "#result-set-1"

```
 // Parameters
    SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("MYINPUT1", Types.VARCHAR), // Example input parameter
            new SqlParameter("MYINPUT2", Types.VARCHAR), // Example input parameter
            new SqlParameter("INPUT", Types.VARCHAR), // Input Parameters 
            new SqlOutParameter("RC", Types.VARCHAR), // maybe Return Code 
            new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT", Types.VARCHAR), // Result-Set Mapping - this will solve the LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap
            new SqlReturnResultSet("#result-set-1", (RowMapper<YourPojo>) (rs, rowNum) -> {
                YourPojo example = new YourPojo();
                YourPojo.setWhatEver(rs.getInt("WHATEVER"));
                YourPojo.setWhenEver(rs.getInt("DATE"));
                return example;
            }) };

     SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("MYSP001").withSchemaName("SYSPROC").declareParameters(parameters);

    // Inputvalues
    Map<String, String> inParamMap = new HashMap<>();
    inParamMap.put("INPUT1", "inputvalueExample");      
    inParamMap.put("INPUT2", "inputvalueExample2");
    SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
    Map<String, Object> resultFromSP = simpleJdbcCall.execute(source);
    List<YourPojo> mylist = (List<YourPojo>) resultFromSP.get("#result-set-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the data.  I guess you could loop through keys to see what's in the result and code accordingly.  IE: update-count, multiple results whatever your case is.

```
 Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = this.simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);
            Map.Entry<String,Object> entry = simpleJdbcCallResult.entrySet().iterator().next();
            String key= entry.getKey();
            // Removing "#result-set-1" as object name that holds all the data.
            // That is the default name for SimpleJDBCCall result.
            // Just for aesthetics in Json result.
        return (List<Map<String,String>>)simpleJdbcCallResult.get(key);
```